# Cannot run rake with cron tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, cron, rake, rake-task

I am unable to run rake tasks with cron. The error it throws up is:-

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:199: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 in PATH, mode 040777 
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `materialize': Could not find unf_ext-0.0.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

However, when I run the same rake task directly from the terminal, it works fine. In case of the cron job, as well as while running the rake task directly from the terminal, i cd into the (exact) same directory. Starting the rails server works as well.

What is the problem and how should I resolve this?

Comment: I faced the same problem. Solved!

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18096502/1524350

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your daemon user and your user when you're running it directly. Or it could be a problem with Ruby and/or your cron file commands.

Firstly, use this gem for making cron jobs with rake tasks:
https://github.com/javan/whenever

Then install RVM since you're using the standard ruby library provided by OSX and that can lead to some problems when you're developing various projects. This should fix the permissions error that you have displayed.