# Cannot run rake task in cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, whenever

I'm using whenever gem and my cron job like this:

**schedule.rb**

```
set :path, "/home/user/www/my_app/current"

...

every 60.minutes do
  rake "ts:rebuild", :output => "/home/user/Sphinx/log/search.log"
end
```

This task generate this cron job:

0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/www/my_app/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ts:rebuild --silent >> /home/user/Sphinx/log/search.log 2>&1'

This rake task not running, but it can run from command line. Another, non-rake task works without problem. I think the problem with PATH, but cannot understand how to setup current environment.

Comment: Looks like that's trying to run every 5 minutes...Regardless, the next step is to execute the command it generated directly (removing all the IO redirection stuff), and see what happens: `/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/www/my_app/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ts:rebuild --silent`

Comment: When I run '/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/www/my_app/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ts:rebuild --silent' directly it runs correct and without errors.

Comment: I faced the same problem. Solved!

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18096502/1524350