# Ruby Crontab Rake task fails, but only when command is ran by crontab

Tags: ruby, activerecord, cron

I have a ruby sinatra app that has a rake task that will check a data files against a database using active record. I'm using the whenever gem to run this rake task on a schedule. This was working fine for some time, then after a few days it will hit a failure, and it looks like it's unable to write to the log file. I have a rescue that will email me the error and stack trace, and this is what I'm getting:

```
Broken pipe - 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb:578:in `write'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb:578:in `warn'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb:578:in `rescue in write'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb:562:in `write'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb:382:in `add'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb:456:in `error'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:428:in `rescue in log'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `log'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:286:in `execute'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:220:in `execute'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:224:in `exec_query'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:233:in `select'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:24:in `select_all'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:30:in `select_one'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:36:in `select_value'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:174:in `exists?'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `exists?'
/home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/releases/20131010141756/app/models/clients/test/order_file.rb:39:in `block in create_new_orders'
```

The crontab created by the whenever gem looks like this:

```
0 0,12 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deployer/public/fulfillment_api/releases/20131010141756 && RACK_ENV=production bundle exec rake background_jobs:process_and_email['\''khartnet@gmail.com'\''] --silent'
```

What is strange is that when I past this command into the command line, it runs fine. Even if I switch user to root and run it, it still works without any problems. I'm only getting an error when the crontab runs it.

Comment: When a `crontab` job runs, the `PATH` is set differently than when you just login. You'll need to make sure you set needed `PATH` items in the cron job.

Comment: Hi @mbratch, Thanks for your comment. I tried setting the PATH to the same value I have when I log in, but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: When you run it on the command line, are you doing it just like that, with the `/bin/bash...`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It was a copy and paste. I was just able to get it to run by adding " >> /tmp/cron_log.log" at the end of the command. I'm not sure why this is, but it got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14792306/1512654

I tried to set RVM and log the output. That seemed to get it working. After removing extra parts, I found that I only needed to add " > /tmp/cron_log.log" at the end of the cron task to get this working. I'm not exactly sure the reason this worked. I'm guessing the cron job was having an issue with STDOUT?