# Rake: command not found when running cron job

Tags: ruby, rake, cron

I am running a Ruby app and every minute a script needs to run so that it sends emails out to various users.

The script works when I run it manually, however when running through cron it fails with the error "Rake: command not found".

I'm pretty new to all of this stuff and I know it will be something pretty basic but I can't find anything online that relates - there are some that are close but don't quite fit.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# USAGE - runs rake script on redmine@mycompany for email issue reply facility      in redmine
cd /usr/local/src/redmine-3.0.3
rake -f Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production"host=imap.gmail.com port=993 ssl=1 username=redmine@mydomain.com password=<my_password> --trace
folder=Inbox
allow_override=true
```

And the output from the mail when running the job:

```
Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 08:23:01 GMT
Message-Id: <201508210823.t7L8N1U6031959@ip-172-xx-xx-xxx>
X-Authentication-Warning: ip-172-xx-xx-xxx: ec2-user set sender to root using -f
From: root@ip-172-xx-xx-xxx (Cron Daemon)
To: ec2-user@ip-172-xx-xx-xxx
Subject: Cron <ec2-user@ip-172-xx-xx-xxx> sh /usr/local/bin/redmine-email.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ec2-user>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=ec2-user>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=ec2-user>

/usr/local/bin/redmine-email.sh: line 5: rake: command not found
```

My crontab:

```
*/1 * * * *  sh /usr/local/bin/redmine-email.sh
```

So I have no idea what is going on - I run other cron jobs on this machine with no issues at all.  Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: did you try running the command as `bundle exec rake ...`

Comment: Just tried that now - still get bundle: command not found

Comment: if you are using `rvm` or other ruby version manager, you will have to use the appropriate ruby version otherwise it will take default ruby version.

Comment: have you installed the bundler gem? If not, install it via `gem install bundler`. In newer versions of rvm, it is not added by default.

Comment: I am using rvm, but there is only one version of ruby installed (1.9.3), and it works with our application.  Again, the script runs when run manually, just not when run by cron.  I also have bundler installed (1.10.5).

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792053/rake-cron-job-error/18096502) might help you

Comment: Thanks tekina - I tried using the information there but I still couldn't get it to work.  I tried to change the cron job to contain all commands rather than a shell script - no dice.  And still when I run it manually it works.  This is driving me nuts, it should really be so simple - cron, here is a script, now run it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here was that cron didn't have the PATH information.  Added this and the job runs without an issue.  The following information was entered into crontab and voila.

```
PATH="/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin"
GEM_HOME='/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551'
GEM_PATH='/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global'
MY_RUBY_HOME='/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551'
IRBRC='/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/.irbrc'
RUBY_VERSION='ruby-1.9.3-p551'
```

Thanks for your help everyone, apologies if my terminology is no good but I am still learning.